# How to create custom email notifications (folder specific) in a document library?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, jquery

I have a SharePoint 2007 site which has a document library with several folders. My requirement is that whenever an item is uploaded to a folder, SharePoint should automatically generate an email notification to intended users. I can use workflows but those are not specific to a particular folder. As far as I know, SharePoint does not provide such a functionality out-of-the-box.

Is this possible using SPServices/jQuery? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can create an alert at the folder level within the document library through code

```
 public static void AddFolderAlerts()
 {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("site url goes here"))
                {

                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        SPUser user = web.Users["domainname\\username"];
                        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("folder url goes here");
                        user.Alerts.Add(folder.Item, SPEventType.All, SPAlertFrequency.Immediate);
                        user.Update();

                    }

                }

            });
}
```

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/sharepoint-alerts-list-folders-sub-48730.aspx